# How to smoothly Move a object?

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, exponential

I want to make a line, with the `::before` tag, that moves exponentially to the width of the screen. How could I do this in the best way?

example of exponential growth:
[image]

```css
introductionTextLeftCard img {
  width: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 10%);
}

.introductionTextLeftCard {
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(146, 146, 146, 0.897);
  transform: translate(115%, 30%);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.8);
}

.introductionTextLeftCard h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.introductionTextLeftCard h1::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 2px;
  width: 212px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="introductionTextLeft">
  <div class="introductionTextLeftCard">
    <img src="/img/picture_png.png" alt="Ein Bild von einer Nico ähnlich sehenden Figur.">
    <h1>Nico Proyer</h1>
    <h4>Schüler</h2>
      <div class="introductionTextLeftCardLink">
        <a class="introductionTextLeftCardLinkSingle" href="https://www.instagram.com/gameofnicoyt" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a class="introductionTextLeftCardLinkSingle" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@nicoproyer" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i></a>
        <a class="introductionTextLeftCardLinkSingle" href="https://https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCs3ZRAp-ofA3qxemmYuoGJA" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe you could use any of my samples if not that is also ok, but I'd like to have an explanation, of how to do this.

Comment: Have you investigated SVGs and dynamically drawing a line?

Comment: No, becuase it should be a container, that is moved relative to the screen width

Comment: How are you going to draw the line?

Comment: I use a div with a ::before tag:

.class::before {
content: " ";
width: 200px;
height: 5px;
background-color: aqua;
}

Comment: Are you looking for a cubic bezier function as in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function Maybe ease-in would be sufficient:?